# How to determine calibration accuracy/uncertainty of a linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, uncertainty, calibration

To determine organic carbon concentrations in a water solution from UV spectroscopy I made a calibration curve with known carbon concentrations and measured the UV absorbance. I used R for the data analysis and the data are found below.

My question now is, how to determine the accuracy of my calibration curve. I would like to tell people that I can measure the concentrations with an accuracy of 15% or 4 mg l-1, for example. How can I go on with this? Can I just use the $R^2$ (0.91) and say that I have an uncertainty of 9% (1-0.91)? What is the correct way to do this?

```
concentration <- c(27.2,32.4,16.5,11.6,11.9,9.87,46.0,73.6,75.4,73.1,59.5,49.0,
            79.0,81.6,66.7,26.7)

absorbance <- c(0.764, 0.923, 0.678, 0.373, 0.287, 0.253, 1.660, 2.331, 2.255, 
            2.019, 1.130, 1.858, 2.404, 2.812, 2.362, 0.636)

plot(absorbance, concentration, xlab = "absorbance (254 nm)", ylab = "concentration (mg l-1)")

fit <- lm(concentration ~ absorbance)
abline(fit)
lm_coef <- round(coef(fit), 3) # extract coefficients
myr2 <- format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, digits = 2)
legend("topleft", legend = as.expression(c(bquote(paste("lin. equation: ",
                                                    y == .(lm_coef[2])*x + .(lm_coef[1]))), 
                                       bquote(paste("", R^2 == .(myr2))))), cex = 0.6)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be aware that with calibration your independent variable is the concentration of your standards and the dependent variable is the measured quantity.

Look at package `chemCal` for some nice functions.

```
concentration <- c(27.2,32.4,16.5,11.6,11.9,9.87,46.0,73.6,75.4,73.1,59.5,49.0,
                   79.0,81.6,66.7,26.7)

absorbance <- c(0.764, 0.923, 0.678, 0.373, 0.287, 0.253, 1.660, 2.331, 2.255, 
                2.019, 1.130, 1.858, 2.404, 2.812, 2.362, 0.636)


library(chemCal)

#fit a linear model
fit <- lm(absorbance~concentration)

#plot with confidence and prediction bands
calplot(fit)
```

[image: calibration plot]

```
#limit of detection:
lod(fit)

$concentration
[1] 32.48287

$absorbance
        1 
0.9895864 

#limit of quantification:
loq(fit)

$concentration
[1] 56.84455

$absorbance
       1 
1.753749 

#calculate concentration from given absorbance of 1.5
inverse.predict(fit,1.5)

$Prediction
[1] 48.75498

$`Standard Error`
[1] 8.79395

$Confidence
[1] 18.86115

$`Confidence Limits`
[1] 29.89384 67.61613
```

Reading the help files and references therein might be instructive.